Which results are these from triangles?
I was reading book on statics and after discussing triangle law of forces, it said following.
Any other triangle, whose sides are parallel to those of
the triangle OLN, will have its sides proportional to those
of OLN and therefore proportional to the forces.
Again, any triangle, whose sides are respectively per-
perpendicular to those of the triangle OLN, will have its sides
proportional to the sides of OLN and therefore proportional
to the forces.
I am confused why these are two true ?
Thanks

If I am interpreting correctly, this is basically the "Side-Angle-Side" similarity rule.

Parallel or Perpendicular? In both cases the resulted triangles are similar.

@Moti How ? ......

The triangles created are similar to the original one - If parallel it is trivial. If perpendicular, draw it, you will see clearly (and prove) that the resulting triangle is similar to the original one. I can post a detail answer if this is not enough.:)

@Moti Perpendicular part is not clear

Is the answer clear now?

The red triangle is created by the perpendicular to the sides of the brown triangle. Does this help?

